# SQL DB2 Database Table automatic export to .csv on WIndows

Tags: java, sql, csv, db2, export

I am currently training to be an application developer and am in my second month.

Now I got a task that felt impossible for me.
I have also googled since yesterday but did not find anything.

I have to insert the data from a database that I access with SQL Explorer into a .csv file. and save it on my machine

It should work automatically, but for testing it doesn't have to.

I use Eclipse and program with Java, have seen something on the Internet that it works with MySQL, but the DB2 database is connected with the SQL Explorer.
My plan is a solution, programming in java to update everyday the csv thats basically my task

Sorry if it doesn't fit here on Stackoverflow, I'm totally lost because I'm still in the trial period.

Greetings from Germany

Answer (score 0):

[IBM Data Server Client and driver types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=overviews-data-server-clients).
The [IBM Data Server Driver Package](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/quickorder?source=dbluesearch&product=ibm%2FInformation+Management%2FIBM+Data+Server+Client+Packages&release=11.5.8.0&platform=Windows+64-bit,+x86&searchtype=fix&fixids=*dsdriver*FP000), for example, contains the [Command line processor plus](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-command-line-processor-plus-clpplus) utility which can run various db2 commands, statements and scripts including the Db2 [EXPORT command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-export).

Usage:

From the OS command line:

```
clpplus -nw user/password@host:port/database @s1.sql
```

The contents of the `s1.sql` file used as a parameter above:

```
SET ECHO ON;
EXPORT TO "full\path\to\my_file.csv" of del 
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE;
EXIT
```

You may use whatever valid SELECT statement in the EXPORT command.